# Creating a dummy variable, conditional on matching values for a panel observation

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table which has a dummy variable called `varB`. I want to convert `varB` into a different variable, let's say `new_dummy_var`.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("
ID varA varB varC year
1  3    1    6    1
1  2    1    7    2
2  2    0    7    1
2  1    0    8    2
3  5    1    9    3
3  4    1    4    4
4  2    0    3    1
4  5    0    3    2
5  3    1    9    1
5  2    1    9    2
6  2    0    5    1
6  1    0    6    2
7  5    1    6    1
7  4    0    3    2
8  2    0    3    1
8  5    1    4    2",
header = TRUE)
```

I would like `new_var_dummy` to be `0` in the first entry for the `ID` and `1` in the second entry of the `ID` for all ID's where `varB` is `1` for the whole `ID` pair. For all others the dummy variable is zero.

Desired output:

```
DT <- fread("
ID varA varB varC year new_dummy_var
1  3    1    6    1    0
1  2    1    7    2    1
2  2    0    7    1    0
2  1    0    8    2    0
3  5    1    9    3    0
3  4    1    4    4    1
4  2    0    3    1    0
4  5    0    3    2    0
5  3    1    9    1    0
5  2    1    9    2    1
6  2    0    5    1    0
6  1    0    6    2    0
7  5    1    6    1    0
7  4    0    3    2    0
8  2    0    3    1    0
8  5    0    4    2    0",
header = TRUE)
```

As an example: `varB` is `1` for `ID==1` in both years, so for the new dummy, it is `0` in the first year and `1` in the second year. Similar for `ID==3`

For `ID`'s 7 and 8, not both rows have `varB` is `1` so they become zero.

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
pdataframe <- setDT(pdataframe)[sum(varB, by=ID)==2, new_dummy_var:=sample(c("0","1"),2)  ,by=c("ID","varC")]
```

But this give the warning:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(pdataframe), sum(varB, by = ID) == 2, `:=`(new_dummy_var,  : 
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 0 in column 'new_dummy_var'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

I then tried:

```
pdataframe <- setDT(pdataframe)[sum(varB, by=ID)==2, new_dummy_var:=rep(sample(c("0","1"),2))  ,by=c("ID","varC")]
```

Resulting in the same error..

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the index of 2nd occurrence of 1 in `varB` using `which` and turn that index into 1 and rest all of them to 0 for each `ID`.

```
library(data.table)
DT[, new_dummy_var := +(seq_along(varB) %in% which(varB == 1)[2]), ID]

#    ID varA varB varC year new_dummy_var
# 1:  1    3    1    6    1             0
# 2:  1    2    1    7    2             1
# 3:  2    2    0    7    1             0
# 4:  2    1    0    8    2             0
# 5:  3    5    1    9    3             0
# 6:  3    4    1    4    4             1
# 7:  4    2    0    3    1             0
# 8:  4    5    0    3    2             0
# 9:  5    3    1    9    1             0
#10:  5    2    1    9    2             1
#11:  6    2    0    5    1             0
#12:  6    1    0    6    2             0
#13:  7    5    1    6    1             0
#14:  7    4    0    3    2             0
#15:  8    2    0    3    1             0
#16:  8    5    1    4    2             0
```

which in base R can be done by

```
DT$new_dummy_var <- with(DT, +ave(varB == 1, ID, 
                            FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) %in% which(x)[2]))
```

and in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

DT %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_dummy_var = +(row_number() %in% which(varB == 1)[2]))
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, thank you for your answer. Could you explain a bit more how it works exactly? I am trying to figure out how to change it (I also want to create a dummy var for when only the first ID entry is one), but I cannot figure out how..

Comment: @Tom just change `[2]` to `[1]`, like `DT[, new_dummy_var := +(seq_along(varB) %in% which(varB == 1)[1]), ID]` . To know how it works imagine you have 10 rows in group and 4th row is first 1, So what it does is `1:10 %in% 4` which generates a logical vector and the `+` in front changes the logical vector to integer vector so it becomes `+(1:10 %in% 4)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
DT[, new_dummy_var := as.integer(seq_len(.N) %in% which(varB == 1)[2]), ID]
```

---

Or use `.I`

```
DT[, new_dummy_var := 0]
DT[na.omit(DT[, .I[varB == 1][2], ID]$V1), new_dummy_var := 1]
DT
#    ID varA varB varC year new_dummy_var
# 1:  1    3    1    6    1             0
# 2:  1    2    1    7    2             1
# 3:  2    2    0    7    1             0
# 4:  2    1    0    8    2             0
# 5:  3    5    1    9    3             0
# 6:  3    4    1    4    4             1
# 7:  4    2    0    3    1             0
# 8:  4    5    0    3    2             0
# 9:  5    3    1    9    1             0
#10:  5    2    1    9    2             1
#11:  6    2    0    5    1             0
#12:  6    1    0    6    2             0
#13:  7    5    1    6    1             0
#14:  7    4    0    3    2             0
#15:  8    2    0    3    1             0
#16:  8    5    1    4    2             0
```